# Making main thread wait for an event

Tags: java, multithreading

I am doing a college assignment(to be frank enough). The problem is that I should have 4 client threads running at any time (uptil a number n). So, whenver any thread terminates, a new thread must be spawned.

```
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,InterruptedException

   {
     /* some declarations.. */

     ClientThread client=new ClientThread ();

 Runnable intr =client;

 for(count=1;count<=number;count++)

 {
                 /* If 4 client threads has been spawned, wait until 1 of them exits */
           while(Thread.activeCount()<5) 
            ;
            new Thread(intr).start();
   }


       /* Wait until all other threads exits. */
       while(Thread.activeCount()!=1)
        ;   

 System.out.println("\n The sum of factorials is: "+client.getResult());
   }
```

I want to remove the busy-waiting as it defeats the very purpose of my program. How can i make the main thread `wait` ?? (It shows `wait` is a nonstatic method and cannot be invoked from a static method.) Please help.

Comment: Unless you have made calculating factorial multi-threaded, using multiple threads is likely to be slower than using one.

Comment: I got to calculate the sum of factorials of 'n' numbers: 1!+2!+..+n! and each factorial computation is independent(via a different thread by the server.) Is it still slower?? I got no idea, jst implementing what my prof told. :-/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

java.util.concurrent.**CountDownLatch** is designed for your case.

Define `CountDownLatch doneSignal = new CountDownLatch(4);`

`doneSignal.await()` will wait until `doneSignal.countDown()` is called four times.
So let ClientThreads hold sames reference `doneSignal`, when `run()` exits, call  `doneSignal.countDown()`.

```
class ClientThread implements Runnable {
   private final CountDownLatch doneSignal;
   ClientThread (CountDownLatch doneSignal) {
      this.doneSignal = doneSignal;
   }
   public void run() {
      try {
        //Do something
        doneSignal.countDown();
      } catch (InterruptedException ex) {} 
   }
 }
...
//In main thread
doneSignal.await();
```

Comment: Did this actually work?  It seems like this waits for 4 threads to exit before releasing the main thread whereas I believe the question was for every single time the client thread exited the main thread should immediately spawn another.

Answer (score 5):

Hmm - do you have to do it by hand or does your teacher expect that you discover [`Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool%28int%29)?

That's exactly what a thread pool with four worker threads would do: no more then four clients run in parallel, if one terminates, the free'd worker thread is ready to "get a new job".

---

It's pretty simple:

```
public void test(int threads, int runnables) {
  ExecutorsService pool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(threads);
  Runnable r = new Runnable() {
     public void run() {
       // calculate a factorial or do something else
       System.out.println(Thread.currenThread());
     }
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < runnables; i++)
    pool.execute(r);
}
```

Let `runnables` be bigger then `threads` and you'll see from the result that at most `threads` number of threads are (re-)used to execute the runnables.

Comment: So i got to decide between Executors and CountDownLatch... The CountDownLatch seems pretty easy to implement..

Answer (score 1):

You can write a callback method in your main class, that is called by an exiting thread and spawns a new one. By using a static field in the main class you will keep track of the number of threads spawned to obtain the same effect as the current code.

it would look somehow like this :

```
class Main{

    private static ClientThread client;
    private static Runnable intr;
    private static int count;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       count = 10; //Or something else
       runningThreads = 0;
       client=new ClientThread ();
       intr =client;
       for(i=0;i<5;i++)
          spawnThread();
    }

    private static void spawnThread()
    {
        Thread newThread;
        if(count>0)
        {
            newThread = new Thread(intr);
            newThread.start();
            count--;
        }

        if(count==0)
            System.out.println("\n The sum of factorials is: "+client.getResult());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look @ classes in java.util.concurrent
Specifically
java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch
java.util.concurrent.locks.Condition

Answer (score -1):

For the main thread you can use:

```
Thread.getCurrent().join();
```

This will wait for all the spawned threads to die, before the main thread terminates.