# wait executing block of code for thread dies

Tags: java, multithreading

all i want block of code wait for another thread to die
 where this thread not event thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I've been able to understand, it looks like you want a block of code to be executed after some thread dies, but you don't want Thread.join() to block the current thread? Then execute the whole thing in a yet another thread:

```
new Thread() {
  public void run() {
    someThread.join(); // someThread is the thread that you're waiting to die
    // your block of code
  }
}.start();
```

This will execute the code after someThread dies, but won't suspend the current thread.

Answer (score 7):

I believe this is what [`Thread.join()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) method is for:

> public final void join() throws InterruptedException
>
> Waits for this thread to die.

Comment: if i use join word in event thread ,it will suspend too what i want to suspend a block of code from execute until this thread die

Answer (score 0):

`java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch` can be used here.

Comment: As well as Object's wait() and notify() or even a BlockingQueue. But why use these when there is a safe and consistent method that does exactly what is needed?

Comment: CountDownLatch is a choice, not necessary for this case.

Comment: @sergey response : what i need exactly call function after thread die not suspend the event thread @Shengyuan countDownLatch??? plz write down example

Comment: @Henaway: I post a sample on other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780391/making-main-thread-wait-for-an-event/4780504#4780504